# Pass generic exception through QT's signal/slot system as argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, polymorphism

When I catch an exception, I want to emit a signal and pass that exception to a slot so it can be handled in a different thread. The signal and slot are connected using a Qt:QueuedConnection type.

I first tried this:

```
/*in .h*/
signals:
    void exceptionOccured(const std::exception &e);
public slots:
    void exceptionReceive(const std::exception &e);

/*in .cpp*/
    connect(this,SIGNAL(exceptionOccured(const std::exception&)),this,SLOT(exceptionReceive(const std::exception&)),Qt::QueuedConnection);

try {
    throw std::runtime_error("test");
} catch (std::exception &e) {
    emit exceptionOccured(e);
}
```

This somewhat works, but as QT makes a copy of the referenced object to be placed on the queue, the exceptionReceived slot receives a std::exception type object and all additional information is lost.

I then tried to pass a pointer to the original exception object, but that gives me the problem that by the time the slot is called the actual object has disappeared.

How can I either tell QT to make a correct copy of the exception (the actually application has multiple levels of inheritance from std::exception) or turn the catch'ed exception into some safe pointer type (i.e. copy it from the stack to the heap or so).

P.S.
The object sends the message to itself because the try/catch statement is run from a lambda function using QtConcurrent::run();

Comment: You can wrap an `std::exception` with a class that will do a deep copy of necessary data.

Comment: If you're using C++11 then [`std::exception_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr) would help.

Comment: @AlanStokes Yes, I use C++11 and using std::current_exception() does indeed allow me to use the exception in the other thread. If you make it an answer then I can flag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::exception_ptr`was added to the standard one C++11 in order to solve exactly this problem. `std::current_exception()` lets you get a handle to the current exception, and you can then pass it around and re-throw it in any thread you want.

Details at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr.

Comment: Are you sure it'll always work? [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception). "`std::exception_ptr` [...] holds either a copy or a reference to that exception object (it is implementation-defined if a copy is made)". Exceptions in general need not be copyable, but this generally requires that they be so, and that their copy constructors act appropriately. Furthermore, correct me if I'm wrong, but some if not all standard exception types are not copyable ( `std::range_error`). Yes, base `std::exception` is, but that's not helpful.

Comment: @Kuda I believe all exception types are required to be copyable - `throw x` copies `x` (although the copy may be elided). I also believe `range_error` is copyable. The reason for the copy here being implementation-defined as I recall is to cope with both the MS and GCC models.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the base exception type, then this is a C++ problem, not a Qt problem. You'd need to implement some type of a virtual copy constructor pattern. Once you do, Qt will do the right thing automagically.

One such pattern:

```
class clonable_exception : public std::exception {
protected:
  virtual void clone_to(clonable_exception& dst) const = 0;
public:
  clonable_exception() = default;
  clonable_exception(const clonable_exception& src) {
    src.clone_to(*this);
  }
  clonable_exception & operator=(const clonable_exception& src) {
    src.clone_to(*this);
  }
};
```

All signals and slots should use the `clonable_exception` type instead of `std::exception`.